# Android: ViewAncestor is attached to null?

Tags: android, user-interface, popupwindow

I have `PopupWindow` and `ListView` and `EditText` within (Code complete results and filtering edittext):

> ```
> <!-- list -->
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/Autocomplete.list"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="@dimen/autocomplete_height"/>
>
> <!-- filter -->
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/Autocomplete.filter"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
>
> <!-- info label -->
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/Main.autocomplete_label"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     style="@style/PurchaseLabel"
>     android:text="@string/Menu.settings"
>     android:visibility="gone"/>
> ```

If edittext was not used, windows `dismiss()` works ok. If i type smth in EditText and then it's dismiss i'm getting an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling with view android.widget.EditText@4225ba08 but the ViewAncestor is attached to null
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:381)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:170)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.dismiss(PopupWindow.java:1286)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.dismissPopup(AbsListView.java:5811)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onDetachedFromWindow(AbsListView.java:2859)
        at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:11881)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3773)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3748)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3680)
```

Update: i've found that this is related to adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() and custom filter for ListView.

Comment: have you got any solution?